# C# Match User Inputs to Array

Tags: c#

I'm writing some code where I have some information about customers stored in an array called members (id, initials). I then ask the user for their id and initials and match the inputs to the stored information from array members. If they match I move on. However I get an error in my coding: "an object reference is required to access non-static field method or property". The error comes from the if statements. Any suggestions on how to correct this issue?

Some background info: I have two classes, one called Customer and one called Menu. The Menu is the main class while Customer is the class I reference from.

This is from my Menu class:

```
       int L = 0; 
       string I = "";
       Customer[] members = new Customer[2];
        members[0] = new Customer(3242, "JS");
        members[1] = new Customer(7654, "BJ");

        Console.Write("\nWhat is your Loyalty ID #: ");
        L =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\nWhat is your first and last name initials: ");
        I = Console.ReadLine();

                if (L==Customer.GetId())
                    {
                    if (I == Customer.GetInitials())
                       {
                       Console.WriteLine("It matches");
                       }
                    }
                 else
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("NO match");
                    }
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This from my Customer class

```
    private int id;
    private string initials;
    public Customer ()
    {
    }

    public Customer(int id, string initials)
    {
        SetId(id);
        SetInitials(initials);
    }
    public int GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void SetId(int newId)
    {
        id = newId;
    }
    public string GetInitials()
    {
        return initials;
    }
    public void SetInitials(string newInitials)
    {
        initials = newInitials;
    }
```

Comment: Google 'iterating through an array in c#' and see if you can solve your issue. If not come back and show us hwat you have got.

Comment: You probably mean `if (L == members[0].GetId())`. `Customer` is not an object, it is a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says. You can't access the `GetId()` function of Customer by calling Customer.GetId() because GetId() only works on an instance of Customer, not directly through the Customer class.

```
Customer.GetId(); //this doesn't work
Customer myCustomer=new Customer(); myCustomer.GetId(); //this works
```

To check the user's input against your array of inputs, you need to iterate through the array (or alternatively, use Linq).

I'm going to use a [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), because there's not really a good reason to use arrays in most cases.

```
List<Customer> customers=new List<Customer>();
Customers.Add();//call this to add to the customers list.

foreach(var c in customers)
{
    if(c.GetId() == inputId)
    {
        //match!
    }
     else
    {
        //not a match
    }
}
```

You can also improve your Customer class by using properties, or auto properties (which doesn't need a backing field). Here's an auto property example:

```
public string Id {get; set;} // notice there's no backing field?
```

Using the above auto property syntax would allow you do to this:

```
var customer = new Customer();
string id = customer.Id; // notice there's no parentheses?
```

Properties and auto properties allow for a cleaner syntax than having to write Java-style separate getters/setters.

Comment: Thank you. A little bit too advance for me (beginner), but I appreciate the public string Id {get; set;} part.

Comment: I don't think it's too advanced - this is the basics of the C# language. Which part do you not understand? I'll improve it with a better example if you let me know which part.

Comment: MSDN has excellent examples. [For each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) just iterates over all the items in a collection. It's like a for loop, except you don't have to create a variable to keep track of what position you are at. It's so handy that I almost never use plain for loops these days. [Var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) uses type inference so you don't have to write the type of a variable. This is handy because it's shorter, and it's less things to change when refactoring (improving) code.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Var seems very useful. I will go more in depth with for each.